# Define a custom angular directive in Zeppelin

Tags: angular, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to define a custom angular directive in a paragraph to be reused later in the notebook.

However although the directive seems to register correctly, it doesn't get picked up by the rest of the notebook, the directive does not get executed (no console error)

Is it even possible in Zeppelin, has any one succeeded doing something similar?

Thanks

first paragraph, with directive definition

```
%angular
<script>
angular.module('zeppelinWebApp')
  .directive('customDir', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {data: '=chartData'},
      template: '<div>' +
                  'Hey2' +
                '</div>'  
    }
  });
</script>
```

followed by

```
%angular
<custom-dir></custom-dir>
```

and a jsfiddle where the directive works as expected http://jsfiddle.net/0g92s275/1/